# Quickbooks SQL dump Code from QODBC

Tags: odbc, reverse-engineering, quickbooks

I need to extract Quickbooks SQL structure to make a Diagram about the tables that I need to work with. Could this be possible ?
I think QODC could solve my connection issue but I don't know how to extract SQL dump from it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest reading the answer to this question regarding your alternatives - it's incredibly thorough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608117/connecting-to-quickbooks-database-via-odbc-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access the QuickBooks SQL structure, so you're out of luck. Most versions of QuickBooks are not even based on an SQL backend (only Enterprise edition is), so it's not even applicable to those versions.

QuickBooks provides an XML-based API to adding/modifying/querying/deleting data within it, but does not provide direct SQL access. QODBC is a wrapper around the XML-based API which simply transforms XML requests into SQL requests, and vice versa. It is not reverse-engineering anything, it's simply transforming data from one format/protocol, into another.

You choices are to either use the XML API as is, use QODBC, or use the XML API and do something similar to what QODBC is doing by transforming the XML into an SQL-friendly format. I've done something similar with my PHP code, schema and code linked below:

- [MySQL Schema](http://consolibyte.com/demo/quickbooks/sql/phpMyAdmin/)
- [QuickBooks PHP Framework](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=9164)

Comment: Would you please give me more information about this? perhaps examples of reading and writing with this php framework?

Comment: Reading and writing is as simple as doing SQL INSERTs, UPDATEs, and SELECTs. We have support forums here: http://www.consolibyte.com/forum/ and some additional documentation on our wiki: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_sqlmirror

Comment: I just imported your MsSQL Schema but there is no relations between tables is there any way to get this? All your tables are MyISAM.. Can be imported like InnoDB?

Comment: These questions are better posed on our support forums: http://www.consolibyte.com/forum/

Answer (score 0):

You can install QODBC, then setup a linked table in Sql Server Mgmt Studio.
From there, you can more or less query the tables out of QuickBooks into tables in a SQL Svr database.

Answer (score 0):

With QuickBooks Enterprise 2011 this changed, and you can have real ODBC access (although with limited rights and to a limited amount of tables) and then use an SQL tool to map via the ODBC access.

Answer (score 0):

QODBC publishes data layouts for all of the tables it exposes [here](http://www.qodbc.com/schema.htm). The format is really nice if you want to correlate a field on the QuickBooks screen to a table, which is usually what you need in a QuickBooks integration design process.